# enable the array of textboxes php javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, textbox

I got the array of disabled text boxes from the database. When I click on edit button it should enable all the text boxes which are in array. But i could only enable the first text box. Here is the code.


code for edit button:

```
<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="enable();" />
```

function enable()

```
function enable(){
document.getElementById("instance_name").disable = false;
document.getElementById("host_name").disable = false;
}
```

array:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT user_instance.instance_name, user_instance.host_name FROM
dba_account, user_instance WHERE dba_account.account_id = user_instance.account_id AND 
dba_account.account_id = '$accid'");

while($note = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
<inut type='text' name='instance_name' id='instance_name' disabled='disabled' 
value='$note[instance_name]' size='25' />
<input type='text' name='host_name' id='host_name' disabled='disabled' 
value='$note[host_name]' size='25' />
}
```

I am getting all the disabled textboxes, but i can not anable them all. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Isn't it `disabled` instead of `disable`? Fix your javascript.

Comment: yes it is. it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving the same ID to multiple elements.  Each ID can only be unique to one element, so once javascript finds the first ID, it stops.  I'd give it a `class="instance_name"` instead and then get the elements by class instead. You could do something like this:

```
function enable(){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.getElementsByClassName('instance_name'), 
                                  function(element){
                                      element.removeAttribute('disabled');
                                  });
}
```

Comment: OK. I'll give it a try! - rickm

Comment: hey @rickm when I do document.getElementByClassName("instance_name").disabled = false; it is not working. It is asking me for item("").

Comment: and when i assign the value to item('0') then it is enabling the first textbox. but it is not enabling all.

Comment: @user1489064 I did not understand the context of your question.`rickm`'s suggestion is correct about classes.And see the sample I have provided in `rickm`'s answer.

Comment: @Engineer - it is working ...Thnak You for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: GUYS!!! I encountered a new problem. How can I update this array of text boxes? Table name is `user_instance` and field are `account_id` `instance_name`, `host_name`. Any suggestions??? I also posted a question. URL:`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295994/update-a-specific-record-from-the-list-of-array-mysql` for detail explanation.