# update a specific record from the list of array mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, record

I have a table `user_instance`. It has three fields: `account_id`, `instance_name`, `host_name`.
For Example, the records are like this.

```
account_id     instance_name      host_name
------------------------------------------
    1          instance_name1     localhost
    1          instance_name1     % 
    1          instance_name2     localhost
    2          instance_name1     localhost
```

And I am getting instance_name and host_name in an array of text boxes.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT user_instance.instance_name, user_instance.host_name FROM
dba_account, user_instance WHERE dba_account.account_id = user_instance.account_id AND 
dba_account.account_id = '1'");

while($note = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
<inut type='text' name='instance_name' class='instance_name' disabled='disabled' 
value='$note[instance_name]' size='25' />
<input type='text' name='host_name' class='host_name' disabled='disabled' 
value='$note[host_name]' size='25' /> 
}
```

now when I click on the update button, it should update the specific record that I have made changes to. For example, if I change instance_name `instance_name1` or host_name `localhost` of account_id `1`, then it should update that record. I appreciate any help.

Comment: use appropriate condition to chose your specific record

Comment: PHP's `ext/mysql` (the `mysql_*` family) is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Please use [something else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are never executing an [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html) command.

Comment: let's say I am updating instance_name `instance_name1` to `instance_name5` of account_id `1`. I tried this UPDAT qurey: `UPDATE user_instance SET instance_name = '$_POST['instance_name']' WHERE account_id = '1';` but the problem I am facing is, account_id `1` has multiple records in instance_name. How can I update just one specific record?

Comment: A table should have a unique id for each record.  So if you have order numbers or anything of that nature, you should include that in the table.  Otherwise you can use WHERE account_id = 1 AND instance_name = 'name'; to narrow the search down more, but there should be a unique record ID for each row (EX: order number).  It sounds to me like you are just using 1 table to hold everything, where you can use multiple tables.  If you are new to SQL go to www.sqlcourse.com and it will take you through a lot of how to perform specific updates.